# English and Greek UTF characters difference

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, optimization, arduino

I have defined the same char array with English and Greek characters.

```
char myText[]="ΗΤΙΑ ΗΤΙΑΑΑ ΛΟΥΛΟΥΔΙΑΣΜΕΝΗ!!!1234567890";
//  char myText[]="HTIA HTIAAA LOULOUDIASMENH!!!1234567890";
```

When I print the length with `strlen(myText);`of the char array the first one that has Greek UTF8 characters has length of 63 characters but the second has 39. Why does this happened? Who can I fix this or  the proper question is how to syntax Greek Unicode Greek character so the program understand them correctly?

I send the char array to a led matrix and i message does not display on screen as it does when the chars are English. It seems that Greek characters or non-ASCII characters are bigger than one byte.

I have a switch function that check the characters and returns an appropriate byte array for each letter.I have set the default case of the switch to the character `!`
So instead of getting `HTIA HTIA` I get `!H!T!I!A!`. So my switch understands the Greek character as more than 1 byte and returns first the default case witch is `!` and then the correct character.

Also when I try to print the text I get error on the serial monitor(the characters does not display correctly).

Comment: What does your `length` function look like? Post it.

Comment: Seems to be reasonable... What problem you have with that? (obviously non-ASCII characters are longer in UTF8, so...)

Comment: So will this get fixed if i give it in \uXXXX unicode format?also isn't supposed to be 8bit since it is UTF8?

Comment: " isn't supposed to be 8bit since it is UTF8?" :) - Not sure what exactly you mean here... Consider reading something about [Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: I'm curious how you expect 8 bits to represent somewhere around a hundred thousand possible values...

Answer (score 1):

Since UTF-8 characters can have multiple bytes, and strlen just counts the number of bytes until the first null character, strlen will overcount the length of UTF-8 strings.  One solution is to use [mbstowcs()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/) to convert the string to a wide character string, then [wcslen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcslen/) to get the length of the wide-character string.

P.S. [Here](http://goo.gl/jB4cLg) is a demonstration of the effect mentioned in the question.

Comment: well i want to send the array to a led screen i have the funtions to do this but i see that everytime i send a greek character or an non-AScii i get 2 bytes the first is wrong and the second is the exact character in greek

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding, so some characters take only one byte while others take several.

If you are processing the string character-by-character using a `switch` statement, then you should probably use a wide-character string instead:

```
#include <stddef.h>

wchar_t myText[]= L"ΗΤΙΑ ΗΤΙΑΑΑ ΛΟΥΛΟΥΔΙΑΣΜΕΝΗ!!!1234567890";
```

A wide-character has type `wchar_t` instead of `char`, and is intended to be large enough to store any single character in the current locale.  A wide-character string constant is prefixed with the `L` character.

In your `switch` statement you can use wide-character constants in your case expressions (which are also prefixed by the `L` character):

```
switch (c)
{
    case L'Λ':
    /* handle capital lambda */
    break;

    case L'Α':
    /* handle capital A */
    break;

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: tho i ha e included stddef.h i get that wcslen() can not be resolved but it is in the list of the function that i can use.

Comment: @kyrpav: `wcslen()` is declared in `wchar.h`.  If you include `wchar.h` you don't need `stddef.h` as well.

Comment: tho i have included wcharacter.h it still does not recognize the function

Comment: @kyrpav Try `#include <cwchar>`

Comment: :( sorry this can not work the libs exept that do not exist they also give this error with the wcslen() function